# Font Styling on Safari since El Capitan Update

Tags: css, fonts, safari, webkit, google-font-api

Since the El Capitan Update I am having some styling issues on my website's fonts in Safari.

The font somehow seams blurry. Please see the screenshot attached.
[image: Screenshot]

If you look closely, you will see white lines on the font.

Here is the code in my main.scss:

```
body {
background: $white;
font-family: "Lato", Lato, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-weight: 300;
color: #333;
// font-style: normal;
// font-weight: normal;
// font-variant: normal;
// text-transform: none;
// line-height: 1;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;   }
```

Do you have any idea how to address this problem?

Thanks!
Flo

Comment: Can you share a link?